# the item you requested is not available for purchase - in-app billing

Tags: android, mobile, in-app-billing

I have a trouble of testing android billing!
Someone help me! I do an example:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    IabHelper mHelper;

    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mQueryFinishedListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
        public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory){
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                // handle error
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "debug: Query occur error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "debug: Query successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "debug: " + inventory.getSkuDetails("product_1").getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "debug: " + inventory.getSkuDetails("product_2").getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }
    };

    IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase)
        {
            if (result.isFailure()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "debug: purcharge failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("Purchrge", "Error purchasing: " + result);
                return;
            }
            switch (purchase.getSku()){
                case "product_1":
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "debug: purcharge product 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case "product_2":
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "debug: purcharge product 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String base64EncodedPublicKey = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAn9zEWzKIvk/hScbZyrZ6HE4y679DUIQPsxfz0mQJmnv3RYCdd7Zcy+peOtnvRyZzmbrAcYmW1FOsH/3dJwuAmdO+Wd9HyDre+vJwAAQ/QI2WA4lbWSl4jVEr7AX9p3J8pBIy3UKRmhjk/PFN8N1jYDUnnPbZJnSkd6eRpiET+MMUsNHIoCxXzmqXvy3bFh/L61gtqUW/acOkWuXnLkn6rVVBzHUL9YLeVRdnN86DnejJySe8DniiAH0sfMP7wxU2y4GoKPjXDeZFNZr4ii22re7ogpIjEfUEb3+FxtxfbjPFz6hONsy/NofkEDznci5fPk8FtulhVbkJ82Rpiq6BXQIDAQAB";
        mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

    }

    public void query(View view){
        mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                    Log.d("Billing error: ", "Problem setting up In-app Billing: " + result);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "debug: IAB is not set up!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                // Hooray, IAB is fully set up!
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "debug: Hooray, IAB is fully set up!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                List additionalSkuList = new ArrayList();
                additionalSkuList.add("product_1");
                additionalSkuList.add("product_2");
                mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, additionalSkuList, mQueryFinishedListener);
            }
        });
    }

    public void pay(View view){
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, "product_1", 10001, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
        mHelper = null;
    }
}
```

**activity_main**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Query"
        android:onClick="query"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pay"
        android:onClick="pay"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

when deploying the app, I got two buttons (Query, Pay). I click Query button before clicking Pay button.

Then I get the form with:

> The item you requested is not available for purchase

I signed the APK in release mode. The app is published and the Products are active. Someone help me with finding our the problem?

Comment: It happened to me also, but my case was that, accidentally, the android package name was change to some kind of default value (I was using Unity). When I changed the package name to the one published in the Google Play, worked again.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure the `android:versionCode` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file you are testing, has the same version number as in the `.apk` you uploaded as your current active alpha version in the Developer Console.

This at least was my issue as I was getting the same error.

Comment: Here is the message I am getting when adding the version code to my android manifest.xml "The versionCode value is not used. It is always overridden by the value specified in the Gradle build script. "